# OpenCV (4.5.2., C++) Apply matrix (4*4) to image and write to file results in white file (or strange color result)

Tags: c++, flutter, opencv, ffi, colormatrix

I am getting an image from the mobile phone device camera and want to use OpenCV to apply color filters to the images.
(Software/System is a Flutter App that uses Foreign Function Interface (FFI) to interact with the OpenCV Library in C++)

---

I followed below question and tried to implement the solution, but so far I get only totally white images.

- StackOverflow: [OpenCV help me with Sepia kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15869198/opencv-help-me-with-sepia-kernel)

---

##### I ended up with the following code trying to achieve it:

**transform function (not working)**

```
    void filter_1(char* inputImagePath, char* outputImagePath) {
        Mat input = imread(inputImagePath);
        Mat output = input.clone();

        Mat filter = (Mat_<float>(4,4) << 0.272, 0.534, 0.131, 0.0,
                                          0.349, 0.686, 0.168, 0.0,
                                          0.393, 0.769, 0.189, 0.0,
                                          0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        transform(output, input, filter);
        imwrite(outputImagePath, input);
    }
```

**filter with 0~255 values instead of 0.0~1.0 (also not working)**

```
       Mat filter = (Mat_<int>(4,4) <<69, 136, 33, 0,
                                      88, 174, 42, 0,
                                      99, 196, 48, 0,
                                      0, 0, 0, 255);
```

---

So my question would be how to apply the filter and save the result successfully for further use? The sample filter here should result in a Sepia effect on the image.

---

### UPDATE (2021.07.21)

- Removed filter2d function and related text to avoid confusion.
- Removed link to filter2d related question in SO

  - (Just for notice: StackOverflow: [OpenCV apply my own filter to a color image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27615913/opencv-apply-my-own-filter-to-a-color-image/) )
- Added sample for 0~255 values matrix

---

Comment: filter2d is wrong here, it's a spatial filter, not a color filter (best to remove that from the post entirely, it only confuses people). `transform` is correct. the problem is the scale of values. check the maximum value. if the output is floating point, the assumed range is probably 0.0 to 1.0, not 0 to 255. scale (multiply) your values accordingly.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for the info. i removed the filter2d content. i tried to use a mat with 0~255 values but that also results in just plain white.

Comment: as I tried to explain in the second half of my previous comment, that depends on the **data type** because imshow/imwrite are sensitive to that. it does not do any scaling. if your pixels are 0..255 and your filter is 0..255, the result will be 0..195075 (255*255*3 worst case). **you** have to scale your result or your filter properly. the range of the **output** values matters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was able to get the data type and to solve my problem. Actually the code from the the question works. Not sure what the problem exactly was but maybe that i forgot to remove the `IMREAD_COLOR` in `imread(inputImagePath, IMREAD_COLOR);`